# Duda acerca del uso de modularizacion y TAD en C

Tags: c

Escribo por un error que llevo obteniendo hace un tiempo en C+- (una variante creada por mi universidad, casi igual a C pero con algunas menos funcionalidades, con archivos de extension .cpp ya que usa un compilador de C++ en code blocks.. )  acerca de lo siguiente:

```
**...\Practica5.cpp|41|undefined reference to `MetodosAlmacen::ListarAlmacen()'|**

**44|undefined reference to `MetodosAlmacen::AltaDron()'|**

**|47|undefined reference to `MetodosAlmacen::AltaPaciente()'|**

**|50|undefined reference to `MetodosAlmacen::BajaDron()'|**

**|53|undefined reference to `MetodosAlmacen::NuevoPedido()'|**

**|56|undefined reference to `MetodosAlmacen::AsignacionDronesDiaria()'|**

**|59|undefined reference to `MetodosAlmacen::ListaMensualPedidosDron()'|**

**|62|undefined reference to `MetodosAlmacen::InformeMantenimiento()'|**

**|65|undefined reference to `MetodosAlmacen::DibujarGraficasDron()'|**
```

esto ocurre en cada una de las opciones del switch case. Estoy usando 3 archivos: el archivo **Practica5.cpp**(en el que se encuentra el int main con el menu de opciones), el archivo de modulo **GestionAlmacen.h** (donde tengo definidos los tads), y **GestionAlmacen.cpp** (en el cual llevo a cabo la implementacion de los procedimientos declarados en el modulo .h y que corresponden con cada una de las opciones del menu del archivo Practica5.cpp), aqui adjunto cada uno de estos archivos, sin terminar ya que de momento sólo estaba viendo como lo iba a estructurar, pero no puedo avanzar debido a ese error, asi que procedo a adjuntar los archivos:

**Practica5.cpp:**

```
/***********************************************************
* Descripcion: PRACTICA 5.
************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "GestionAlmacen.h"
int main (){
  char respuesta;
  bool continuar=true;
  MetodosAlmacen funciones;
  system("pause");
  do{
    /*Directiva para limpiar la pantalla*/
    system("cls");
    printf("GESTION DE MantenimientoDrones: \n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("1. Listar Almacen                     (Pulsar I) \n");
    printf("2. Alta Dron                          (Pulsar A) \n");
    printf("3. Alta paciente                      (Pulsar P) \n");
    printf("4. Baja dron                          (Pulsar B) \n");
    printf("5. Nuevo pedido                       (Pulsar N) \n");
    printf("6. Asignar drones                     (Pulsar D) \n");
    printf("7. Lista mensual de pedidos por dron  (Pulsar L) \n");
    printf("8. Informe de mantenimiento           (Pulsar R) \n");
    printf("9. Dibujar graficas del dron          (Pulsar G) \n");
    printf("9. Salir                              (Pulsar S) \n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Teclear una opcion valida (I|A|P|B|N|D|L|R|G|S)?.\n");

    scanf("%c",&respuesta);
  switch(respuesta){
    case 'I':
     funciones.ListarAlmacen();
      break;
    case 'A':
      funciones.AltaDron();
      break;
    case 'P':
      funciones.AltaPaciente();
      break;
    case 'B':
      funciones.BajaDron();
      break;
    case 'N':
      funciones.NuevoPedido();
      break;
    case 'D':
      funciones.AsignacionDronesDiaria();
      break;
    case 'L':
      funciones.ListaMensualPedidosDron();
      break;
    case 'R':
      funciones.InformeMantenimiento();
      break;
    case 'G':
      funciones.DibujarGraficasDron();
      break;
    case 'S':
      continuar=false;
      system("cls");
      break;
    }
    }while(continuar);
}
```

**GestionAlmacen.h :**

```
/*****************************************************************
* Descripcion: Modulo GestionAlmacen con uso de TAD de Practica 5.
*****************************************************************/

#pragma once
const int MAX_Drones = 15;
typedef struct MetodosAlmacen{
        void InicializarVectorAlmacen();
        void ListarAlmacen();
        void AltaDron();
        void AltaPaciente();
        void BajaDron();
        void NuevoPedido();
        void AsignacionDronesDiaria();
        void ListaMensualPedidosDron();
        void InformeMantenimiento();
        void DibujarGraficasDron();
};
typedef struct Almacen{
  int alturamar;

};
typedef struct Pacientes{
    int referenciapaciente;
    char idpaciente;
    int distanciacliente;
    int angulocliente;
    int alturamar;
};
typedef struct Drones{
    int numeroserie;
    char alias;
    int kmh;
    int kmrevh;
    int metrosv;
    int metrosrevv;
};
typedef struct pedidos{
    char fechapedido;
    char nombrefarmaco;
    int pesofarmaco;
    int unidadesfarmaco;
};
typedef Drones TipoVectorDrones[MAX_Drones];
```

y finalmente el **GestionAlmacen.cpp:**

```
/**********************************************************************              
* Descripcion: Fichero de implementacion del modulo 'GestionAlmacen.h'.
***********************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include "GestionAlmacen.h"
void MetodosAlmacen::ListarAlmacen(){
  ...implementacion de ListarAlmacen
}
void MetodosAlmacen::AltaDron(){
    /*...implementacion de AltaDron*/
}
void MetodosAlmacen::AltaPaciente(){
  /*implementacion de AltaPaciente*/
}
void MetodosAlmacen::BajaDron(){
     /*...implementacion de BajaDron*/
}
void MetodosAlmacen::NuevoPedido(){
      /*...implementacion de NuevoPedido*/
}
void MetodosAlmacen::AsignacionDronesDiaria(){
     /*...implementacion de AsignacionDronesDiaria*/
}
void MetodosAlmacen::ListaMensualPedidosDron(){
     /*...implementacion de ListaMensualPedidosDron*/
}
void MetodosAlmacen::InformeMantenimiento(){
       /*...implementacion de InformeMantenimiento*/
}
void MetodosAlmacen::DibujarGraficasDron(){
     /*...implementacion de DibujarGraficasDron*/
}
```

Agradecería que alguien pudiese iluminarme con esto, ya que soy nuevo en el uso de los tipos abstractos de datos y en modularizar proyectos en este lenguaje similar a C.

Answer (score 1):

**Atencion!** Por si a alguien le ocurre un error similar, ya lo solucioné. El problema radicaba en que estaba tratanto de compilar el archivo Practica5.cpp por separado, y esto provocaba que no estuviera bien enlazado a los archivos del modulo (GestionAlmacen.h) y de implementacion del modulo (GestionAlmacen.cpp). La solucion facil es incluir todos tus archivos en un proyecto en code blocks, y compilar y ejecutar este al completo.

Comment: Otra solución es no usar un IDE y compilar manualmente!